# Can't figure out this Kata

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm working on this Kata in CodeWars, and I pass all but one test, but it doesn't say what the error is.  The description says to check both lists for multiplicities.  List a2 is a list of squares of list a1.  I need to check a1 for the square root of all the items in a2, and return false if the array is empty, None, or the square root isn't in a1.

I am hoping to get any tips you might have about not only function (make it more Pythonic), but error handling.  What am I missing?  Why is it not passing?  Thanks in advance.

```
def comp(a1, a2):
    if a1 == [] or a2 == []:
        return False
    if a1 == None or a2 == None:
        return False
    pos_count = 0
    neg_count = 0
    for num in set(a2):
        if num**0.5 in set(a1):
            pos_count += 1
        else:
            neg_count += 1
    if neg_count > 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: For each number in a1; if number times number is not in a2; return False. If a1 numbers are exhausted return True.

Comment: In the shell, try `2 * 2`.  the result is 4, an integer.  Now try `4 ** .5`.  The result is 2.0 a float.  When you take the square root of a number in `a2` the result may be a float with some [floating point errors](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).  When you try to compare that to an integer in `a1`, it may fail the comparison. That's a guess anyway for what is happening.

Comment: Well my floating point error theory may not be correct, I just checked  integers from 0 - 100000, in `a1` and their squares in `a2` - your function worked for all those.

Comment: If you need to test both lists for multiplicity, then if you have `2` in `a1` but no `4` in `a2` wouldn't this function still `return True`? What about 2x`4` in `a2` and only one `2` in `a1`?

Comment: What if `num` is negative? What does `num ** 0.5` give you?

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, wwii, I'm working on that.  You're saying to go at it from the a1 list, not the a2 list (check a2 for the squares instead of checking a1 for the square roots), right?  Why is that better?  I'm just trying to work out my logic for future.  Thx.

Comment: @AChampion, No, it just wants to know if it's in the other list.  It doesn't have to have the same quantity.  Is that what you're asking??

Comment: @PeterWood, thanks, I was forgetting to make it greater than zero.

Comment: I finally figured it out.  I realized I needed to put a set of a1 squared against the set of a2.  Also took out the empty set error handling.

    def comp(a1, a2):
        if a1 is None or a2 is None:
            return False
        num_squared = []    
        for num1 in a1:
            num_squared.append(num1**2)   
        if set(a2) == set(num_squared):
            return True
        else:
            return False

Answer (score 0):

Your can improve the code you posted as a comment:

```
def comp(a1, a2):
    if a1 is None or a2 is None:
        return False
    num_squared = []
    for num1 in a1:
        num_squared.append(num1**2)
    if set(a2) == set(num_squared):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

You can build sequences using a comprehension expression. You build a list by appending squares to an empty list, but you could do it like so:

```
num_squared = [num ** 2 for num in a1]
```

You create a temporary `set` object `set(num_squared)`. However, you could build a set in the same way as the list instead:

```
num_squared = {num ** 2 for num in a1}
```

If you have a boolean expression and then return `True` else `False` you can replace it with the expression itself:

```
return set(a2) == set(num_squared)
```

Applying all these changes you can get:

```
def comp(a1, a2):
    if a1 is None or a2 is None:
        return False
    else:
        return set(a2) == {num ** 2 for num in a1}
```

edit: Just to note:

Empty lists evaluate as `False` in boolean expressions:

```
>>> bool([])
False
```

Also, `None` evaluates `False`:

```
>>> bool(None)
False
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @peter-wood.  I know my code is clunky at this point, and I appreciate your guidance to streamline it!